# What data source ID to use for Google Fit REST heart rate query?

Tags: rest, google-fit, heartrate, google-fit-api

I'm trying to retrieve aggregate daily heart rate summary data using the [Google Fit REST API](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/aggregate), but I'm struggling because either I'm missing something or the documentation seems to be very incomplete. I've successfully managed to retrieve aggregate daily step count by following [one of the few available examples](https://developers.google.com/fit/scenarios/read-daily-step-total):

**Request URL**

`https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate`

**Request body**

```
{
  "aggregateBy": [{
    "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta",
    "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"
  }],
  "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 },
  "startTimeMillis": 1438705622000,
  "endTimeMillis": 1439310422000
}
```

I can't find any example for reading heart rate, so I'm trying to modify this for heart rate. I found [this list of data types](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/aggregate) where it has this data type: `com.google.heart_rate.summary` but there isn't any information on what the `dataSourceId` should be. I tried just omitting it but I get this error:

> no default datasource found for: com.google.heart_rate.summary

Does anybody know what I need to use for dataSourceId, or have a link to any decent documentation on data sources?

Comment: Don't set both `dataTypeName` and `dataSourceId`: setting a specific data source id will take precedence over setting the data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [list the data sources available](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataSources/list) for a given data type, for example :

**Method**

```
GET
```

**Request URL**

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataSources?dataTypeName=com.google.heart_rate.summary
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you'll probably find a source either for `com.google.heart_rate.summary` or `com.google.heart_rate.bpm` to meet your needs, including merged sources.

Comment: Yep, this seems to be the only way to find out - I don't understand why there isn't a documented list somewhere. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

For resting heart rate, I use this:

```
"derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm"
```

For heart rate or BPM, I use this:

```
"derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm"
```

For completeness, I have included the datasources that I am using below for various readings:

```
DATA_SOURCE = {
    "steps": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_step_deltas",
    "dist": "derived:com.google.distance.delta:com.google.android.gms:from_steps<-merge_step_deltas",
    "bpm": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm",
    "rhr": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:resting_heart_rate<-merge_heart_rate_bpm",
    "sleep" : "derived:com.google.sleep.segment:com.google.android.gms:sleep_from_activity<-raw:com.google.activity.segment:com.heytap.wearable.health:stream_sleep",
    "cal" : "derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_activities",
    "move": "derived:com.google.active_minutes:com.google.android.gms:from_steps<-estimated_steps",
    "points" : "derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes",
    "weight" : "derived:com.google.weight:com.google.android.gms:merge_weight"
}
```

Depending on the datasource, sometimes it will provide an array of points. You can then choose to take sum, mean, median, etc of all points in the array accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! This seem to work well for fetching resting heart rate data points from Google Fit. I am curious as to how you figured the datasource for resting heart rate. Just want to make sure that this is not something that Google would/can change at a later time without any notification.

Comment: Just to clarify, my concern in the previous comment was mainly because resting heart rate is not exposed as a standard data type from Google Fit.

Comment: What about Walking Heart Rate and Recovery Heart Rate? Is there a way to calculate that in Google Fit?